# Does String Value Exists in a List of Strings | Redshift Query

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have some interesting data, I'm trying to query however I cannot get the syntax correct. I have a temporary table (`temp_id`), which I've filled with the `id` values I care about. In this example it is only two ids.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_id (id bigint PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO temp_id (id) VALUES ( 1 ), ( 2 );
```

I have another table in production (let's call it `foo`) which holds multiples those ids in a single cell. The `ids` column looks like this (below) with ids as a single string separated by "|"

```
ids 
-----------
1|9|3|4|5
6|5|6|9|7
NULL
2|5|6|9|7
9|11|12|99
```

I want to evaluate each cell in `foo.ids`, and see if any of the `ids` in match the ones in my `temp_id` table.

Expected output

```
ids         |does_match
-----------------------
1|9|3|4|5   |true
6|5|6|9|7   |false
NULL        |false
2|5|6|9|7   |true
9|11|12|99  |false
```

So far I've come up with this, but I can't seem to return anything. Instead of trying to create a new column `does_match` I tried to filter within the `WHERE` statement. However, the issue is I cannot figure out how to evaluate all the `id` values in my temp table to the string blob full of the `ids` in `foo`.

```
SELECT
    ids,
FROM foo
WHERE ids = ANY(SELECT LISTAGG(id, ' | ') FROM temp_ids)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would work, however not sure about performance

```
SELECT
    ids
FROM foo
JOIN temp_ids 
ON '|'||foo.ids||'|' LIKE '%|'||temp_ids.id::varchar||'|%'
```

you wrap the IDs list into a pair of additional separators, so you can always search for `|id|` including the first and the last number

Comment: This ended up working well. Performance is slow, but it allows me to change the amount of `ids` in my temp table. Thanks!

Comment: The performance will be slow in this query, because 1- varchar conversions for every ids field 2 - like is always slow

Answer (score 1):

The following SQL (I know it's a bit of a hack) returns exactly what you expect as an output, tested with your sample data, don't know how would it behave on your real data, try and let me know

```
with seq AS (                # create a sequence CTE to implement postgres' unnest
select 1 as i union all      # assuming you have max 10 ids in ids field, 
                             # feel free to modify this part
select 2 union all
select 3 union all
select 4 union all
select 5 union all
select 6 union all
select 7 union all
select 8 union all
select 9 union all
select 10)

select distinct ids, 
    case             # since I can't do a max on a boolean field, used two cases 
                     # for 1s and 0s and converted them to boolean
       when max(case        
          when t.id in (
                select split_part(ids,'|',seq.i) as tt
                  from seq
                  join foo f on seq.i <= REGEXP_COUNT(ids, '|') + 1
                 where tt != '' and k.ids = f.ids)
          then 1 
          else 0 
          end) = 1 
       then true 
       else false 
    end as does_match
from temp_id t, foo 
group by 1
```

Please let me know if this works for you!

Comment: This worked as well, but I ended up choosing a different answer, as it was simpler to implement. Thanks for taking the time to answer 